# How to upload UIImage to Server in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, afnetworking, multipartform-data

What my project does is takes pictures with a custom camera and adds them to an NSMutableArray. Then, I grab those images and submit them to my API that accepts images. I have tried almost every solution that I have found on StackOverflow and none have worked for me. I've used Multipart Request using AFNetworking and even with just NSURLRequests.

There are two solutions that actually submit to my API, however, the file gets shown as *******.amazonaws.com/2020/10/21/090522h. It doesn't add the extension to the image, so when I try and display that image back on my app, the image is broken.

[Custom Camera View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRTKK.png)

[View that Displays Image Array after Images are taken with Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8a9N.png)

This gets returned after I press submit with the AFNetworking solution, but image is broken.

```
2020-10-21 10:40:57.715622-0500 WFM App[24455:5876263] Response: {length = 8, bytes = 0x2053554343455353}
2020-10-21 10:40:57.716223-0500 WFM App[24455:5876263]  SUCCESS
```

Here's the one that worked using **AFNetworking**:

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(transporterImagesArray[0], 0.7);

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager POST:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                    name:@"fileToUpload"
                                fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

        // etc.
    } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Here's one that worked with **NSURLRequests**:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(transporterImagesArray[0], 0.7);

    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=fileToUpload\r\n\r\n", @"imageCaption"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", @"Some Caption"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add image data
    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=fileToUpload;"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the request
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if(data.length > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Success uploading Image!");

            picturesDisplayViewController *home = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];

        }
    }];
```

I would appreciate some help or advice, I have been stuck on this for a whole day now, and I need to move on. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your API is working on the server side? Maybe calculate e.g. MD5 just to see if file is the same, in which case, you need to fix the name issue not the upload.

Comment: @skaak yeah it does work, just tested it and it successfully submits into the server with the same name. However, in the app, it just adds it like 130509h.

Comment: Ok but then this code is correct as it does upload correctly? I think the server gives that extension on the server side and you need to fix it on that side?

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand - you say the file gets shown with that funny name and I assume it is on the server side. But here you say the app adds the funny stuff? You can clarify but it is normal when uploading / downloading that the name gets a bit mangled. You can put a name in the headers to resolve it but you have to be ready for this kind of situation anyhow.

Comment: @skaak Well I tested the API, I used postman to upload an image and it worked, it gave the proper name and displays correctly on my app by grabbing the link from aws and showing the image. For the code in the app, I upload a UIImage and when it submits to the server the aws link has that funny name. I downloaded the file and it shows it as a TextEdit Document with Zero Bytes, so I guess nothing actually gets sent.

Comment: @skaak Nevermind got it to work! I am using an ELCImagePicker before taking pictures I ask if they want to select from gallery or take the images, so I followed that tutorial for uploading them and it worked! I appreciate your help though! https://jmsliu.com/3241/select-and-upload-multiple-photos-from-gallery-or-camera-in-ios.html

Comment: Ok great stuff, I'm glad you solved it.